# Animating the logo automatically with a pop-up info on being clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="open-popup">Open popup</button>

<div id="my-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">
  Inline popup
</div>
<style>
#open-popup {padding:20px}
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 40px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#open-popup').magnificPopup({
    items: [
      {
        src: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Peter_%26_Paul_fortress_in_SPB_03.jpg/800px-Peter_%26_Paul_fortress_in_SPB_03.jpg',
        title: 'Peter & Paul fortress in SPB'
      },
      {
        src: 'http://vimeo.com/123123',
        type: 'iframe' 
      },
      {
        src: $('<div class="white-popup">Dynamically created element</div>'), // Dynamically created element
        type: 'inline'
      },
      {
        src: '<div class="white-popup">Popup from HTML string</div>',
        type: 'inline'
      },
      {
        src: '#my-popup', 
       type: 'inline'
      }
    ],
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    type: 'image'
});
<script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make a logo float to the right automatically when clicked and make a pop out appear with some info.
Right now I used a button but I want to use a logo..so how can I put in the image instead of the button and also the pop up to appear when clicked on that logo image.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. You could use css animations or Jquery or an animation library like velocityjs. Have you tried using any of these?

Comment: Welcome Ankit. You'll need to provide some code and explain what you've tried so far - and ask a very specific question about code. Try making a test here:  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @sheriffderek  I need help here

Answer (score 0):

To use an image as the *trigger* for the pop-up window, it looks like you're using the `id` "open-popup." You can remove the button and add an image or put an image in the button (I like buttons, but you have to take measure to *unstyle* it) - so a `<a>` tag - or whatever you like + add the `id` of "open-popup."

..button id="**open-popup**">...

...$('#**open-popup**').magnificPopup({...

As far as moving the logo on click... you can add a class with jQuery/JavaScript and that class can do the animation.

### jQuery

```
$('.element').on('click', function() {
 $(this).addClass('active'); // $(this) refers to the element clicked in this case
});
```

### styles

```
.element {
  transition: .5s; // set speed (look up other options)
}

.element.active {
  transform: translate(50%, 0); // random movement example
}
```

There are many different pop-up / light-boxes. If magnificPopup isn't enjoyable, try another.